# Javascript random variable

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, it works but it only shows the one value all the time how do I fix it so it randomly shows between the 2?

```
 var a, b;
var index = Math.random();
if (index < 0.5) {
    // operate on a

   var firstVId = '4L5g2kN9oUU';
} else {
    // operate on b
   var firstVId = '6Z1y3b46A1k';
}
```

Comment: Which one does it "show" "all the time"?

Comment: Why do you have `a` and `b`? Just deal with `firstVId` i.e. `console.log(firstVId)` at the end. Of course the code is not perfect but still OK.

Comment: What do you mean by *"show"*? `firstVId` is being assigned to either of those values at a 50% chance for each. You need to show the part where there are problems; nothing in this code is "shown all the time", what is the output?

Comment: The first one 4L5g2kN9oUU keeps showing. Is there an easier way to random between both?

Comment: The code you're showing works fine, randomly selecting between the two values equally. What else are you doing, that you haven't shown, that might cause the issue you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as expected. If you add some `console.log` statements to debug, you can see the behavior. It is likely that you are just generating random numbers that fall under a. Take a look at this http://jsbin.com/nekaqubube/edit?js,console

and keep hitting run in the console until you get index values that fall under both.